# Save edits before disconnecting users from enterprise geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, enterprise

Is there any method that enables the Administrator to save the users edits before disconnecting them for an enterprise geodatabase. Because I am disconnecting users  as shown  in the screenshot, but  if they didn’t save their edits before disconnecting them all edits will be lost.

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 , and SQL server 2014

[image]

Comment: No, there is no way to externally force a  number of commands and a database commit on a remote application.

Comment: You need to contact USER1 and have them disconnect in the correct manner.

Comment: Many thanks guys, but dont you think its an important function that should be included, since the Administrator may not have any contact to the users of his database.

Comment: While any unsaved edits will be lost if a session is killed, this is a better outcome than to save edits without integrity. As the GDBA/DBA, communication with the editing stakeholder who made the edits would be needed before any edits would be committed by such a tool. Even in a versioned environment, committing "bad" edits and then allowing a post/reconcile/compress to occur before someone noticed the potential mistake would lead to a garbage in/garbage out situation for whatever the data is used for. Saving edits should always/only be the responsibility of the one who made the edits.

Comment: As an alternative, you could give the editors VPN/Remote ability to connect to their open session and either save their edits or verify they can be discarded. A few phone calls after work or during lunch will probably convince the editors to stop leaving ArcMap open with an active edit session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to remote save another user's edits before disconnecting them from the geodatabase, and as mentioned in the comments this would be a bad idea anyway as you'd potentially (probably?) introduce bad data into your featuer classes particularly if the data wasn't ready to be saved.

An example of this may be where features have been added or moved to aid editing but not actually permanent edits.
Another may just be that the user was never going to save the edits anyway.

While neither of these are really "best-practice" both have the potential to happen often.

Instead of disconnecting your users without notification, perhaps a change in the DBO process would be to notify users ahead of time that maintenance work is going to be carried out and that they need to be disconnected before a specified time otherwise they would be disconnected.  Add that any disconnection means that unsaved edits would be lost.

Alternatively users could be contacted before disconnect to give them an opportunity to save and disconnect themselves.

This isn't just something that happens for geodatabases, it could happen for any type of enterprise database.